# Spring web app javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, http, jax-rs

I'm having some issues running a web app which is basically a URL shortener.

The server have a functionality that allows to upload a CSV file with a list of URLs to short. The code bellow is a method that takes a CSV file from a queue, it reads the file and shorts the URLs in it. The problem comes when I try to send a post request to on of the controllers in my server. The exception that appears is the following:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
```

Here is the code of the method I mentioned:

```
while(true){
    QueueObject qo = csvQueue.take();
    copyFile(qo.getFile());
    File f = new File("temp");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    sc.useDelimiter(",|\\s");
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        String url = sc.next();
        ResponseEntity<ShortURL> res = shortener(url, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(res!=null && ((res.getStatusCode()).toString()).equals("400")){
            String stat = url + " : Failed";
            UpdateMessage um = new UpdateMessage(stat, qo.getUser());  
            Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/urlUploads")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(um, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }
        else{
            String stat = url + " : Success";
            UpdateMessage um = new UpdateMessage(stat, qo.getUser());  
            Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/urlUploads")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(um, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }
    }
    f.delete();
}
```

As I said, the problem is on this specific request (both are basically the same):

```
Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/urlUploads")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(Entity.entity(um, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

The controller I'm trying to reach is this one:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketController.class);

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/urlUploads", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void greet(UpdateMessage update) {
        this.template.convertAndSendToUser(update.getUser(), "/sockets/urlUploads", update.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `try catch` block in your server code. It seems some variable/url is not processed correctly and it throws RuntimeException, so you get 500 error

Comment: You can post the content of um in entity(um, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));